# django time convert from string format to standard

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here the time format is not same in terminal and postman,I do not know why this is so,
is there any way to change the time value?

```
 x = VideoDetails.objects.filter(video__coursemodulevideos__module_id).aggregate(Sum('duration'))
    print('x', x)
    print('x',x['duration__sum'])
 result = { "ho":x['duration__sum'] }
```

In terminal the output is

> x {'duration__sum': datetime.timedelta(seconds=130)}

> x 0:02:10

but in postman

> "hour": {
> "duration__sum": "P0DT00H02M10S"
> }
> Give me a solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you share the serializer with which you work?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `str(…)` of the `timedelta` to the result, so:

```
result = { 'hour': str(x['duration__sum']) }
```